# My adapter does not updating value until i go back and then again come back to that activity. What's the reason

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want that when a user seen message it should replaced text from delivered to seen. But this is happen only when i go back to and again come to that chat activity. My only issue is how to update "delivered" to "seen" when both users chat is open. All other working is fine except this issue.May be adapter not notifying.
here is my chat activity code for seen Messages:

```
private void seenMessage(){

    messageRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                rootRef.child("Messages").child(friendUserId).child(currentUID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:dataSnapshot1.getChildren()){
                            ChatMessage chatMessage=snapshot1.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                            if (chatMessage.getFrom().equals(friendUserId)){
                                HashMap seen=new HashMap();
                                seen.put("isseen",true);
                                snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(seen);
                                snapshot1.getRef().updateChildren(seen);
                                chatMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            chatMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

my Adapter code for this is here

```
  if (userMessageList.size()-1==i){
        if (message.isIsseen()){
            chatMessageViewHolder.seenStatus.setText("Seen");
        }
        else {
            chatMessageViewHolder.seenStatus.setText("Delivered");
        }
    }
    else {
        chatMessageViewHolder.seenStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: I can suggest you check two things first whether `chatMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is getting called from the main thread or not, secondly put a `Log` inside the adapter to check whether it's receiving `notifyDataSetChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` with `addValueEventListener` at your `messageRef`, since the first listener just fires one time to listen to your value at that reference, it will just notify to your adapter once, instead, the second one keeps listening if there is any change at that reference, and you will see the change at realtime without leaving the activity since the adapter will be notified whenever a change is made at that reference.

Comment: I did it but it's still doing the same